# Gameobject rotation around anchored pivot

Tags: unity, c#

I'm looking for the best way to rotate the Camera(EYES) around a center of my character (Player Prototype) because if I turn around, the Camera enter inside the character.
My FPS script is attached to Player Prototype, but the Camera isn't because i have to make particular rotation. So I don't know what I have to do.

- Have will I make the parent? If I will make it, Eyes will sum rotations to those of the parent.
- Or maybe I have to handle this in LateUpdate()?
- With RotationAround() I don't understand how to pass the second argument which is a Vector3, but I have a Quaternion.Euler.

So at this point I accept all the advice or examples of what I can do to solve it.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions could be: that the player only rotates around the straight line Y and the camera only around the X axis.